# How do I add button dynamically with onclick value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I want to add tabs dynamically when I click on a button.
I can add the tab content and the tab button when I clicked the button but the resulting tab button doesn't have the `onclick` attribute.

```
function add_row()
{
  $rowno=$("#numOfKids").val();
  $rowno=$rowno++;
  $buttonNo = "Button"+$rowno;
  $button = "<button class='tablinks' onclick='openCity(event, '"+$buttonNo+"')'>Button"+$rowno+"</button>";
  $("#divAnak").append("<div id='Anak"+$rowno+"' class='tabcontent'><h3>London</h3><p>London is the capital city of England.</p></div>");
  $("#tabs").append($button);
}
```

the above function does add the button but it gives

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, " button1')'="">Button1</button>
```

instead of

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Button1')">Button1</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way :

```
$button = '<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, \'' + $buttonNo + '\')" > Button '+$rowno+' </button>';
```

Comment: @PhilipChristianto happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about when you use `'` and `"` - in your code you close the `onclick='` before `$buttonNo` with a `'`.

It's clear you have an understanding of this to an extent as you have `$button = "` then use `'` within that `"`, but because you start with `"` you have to use `'` for the quotes inside.

You have two choices, either escape the `'` or `"` or add it using the other.

```
$button = "<button class='tablinks' onclick='openCity(event, \""+$buttonNo+"\")'>Button"+$rowno+"</button>";

$button = "<button class='tablinks' onclick='openCity(event, "+'"'+$buttonNo+'"'+")'>Button"+$rowno+"</button>";
```

Neither will give you:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Button1')">Button1</button>
```

but instead:

```
<button class='tablinks' onclick='openCity(event, "Button1")'>Button1</button>
```

which is the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to your mismatched quotes around the `onclick` value:

```
'<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, \'' + buttonNo + '\')">Button' + rowNo + '</button>'
```

```js
function add_row() {
  var rowNo = parseInt($("#numOfKids").val(), 10);
  rowNo = rowNo++;
  var buttonNo = "Button" + rowNo;
  console.log(buttonNo);
  var buttonHtml = '<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, \'' + buttonNo + '\')">Button' + rowNo + '</button>';
  $("#divAnak").append("<div id='Anak" + rowNo + "' class='tabcontent'><h3>London</h3><p>London is the capital city of England.</p></div>");
  $("#tabs").append(buttonHtml);
}

add_row();

function openCity(e, buttonNo) {
  console.log(buttonNo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numOfKids" value="1" />
<div id="tabs"></div>
<div id="divAnak"></div>
```

That being said, it's *far* better practice to avoid using the outdated `on*` event attributes at all. As you've already included jQuery in the page you can simplify this by using a delegated event handler instead and storing any meta data in a `data` attribute:

```js
function add_row() {
  var rowNo = parseInt($("#numOfKids").val(), 10);
  rowNo = rowNo++;
  var buttonNo = "Button" + rowNo;
  var buttonHtml = '<button class="tablinks" data-button-no="' + buttonNo + '">Button' + rowNo + '</button>';
  $("#divAnak").append("<div id='Anak" + rowNo + "' class='tabcontent'><h3>London</h3><p>London is the capital city of England.</p></div>");
  $("#tabs").append(buttonHtml);
}

add_row();

$('#tabs').on('click', '.tablinks', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).data('button-no'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numOfKids" value="1" />
<div id="tabs"></div>
<div id="divAnak"></div>
```

You could potentially do the same with the `add_row()` function, but that depends on when it's being called.

One final thing to note is that you can easily end up with duplicate `id` attributes using this logic, if the same value of `#numOfKids` is used when `add_row()` is called. This should be avoided, so I'd suggest changing your logic to avoid creating these `id` attributes entirely.